# Login using laravel and angular using jwt

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6

I'm using angular and Laravel for user authentication followed this link :

> https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/
> https://www.positronx.io/laravel-angular-token-based-authentication-with-jwt/

Authentication is working, this is login function :

```
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.signin(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {  
          this.responseHandler(result);
      },
      error => {     
        this.errors = error.error;
          if(this.errors.error_message)
          {
            this.toastr.error('', this.errors.error_message);
          }
        // }
      },() => {  
        this.authState.setAuthState(true);
        this.loginForm.reset()
        this.router.navigate(['user/dashboard']);
        this.toastr.success('Success', 'Logged In Successfully');
      }
    );
}

  // Handle response
  responseHandler(data :any ){  
    this.token.handleData(data.access_token);
  }
}
```

issue is when 401 is returned from the server then also it is executing this success block :

```
            this.authState.setAuthState(true);
            this.loginForm.reset()
            this.router.navigate(['user/dashboard']);
            this.toastr.success('Success', 'Logged In Successfully');
```

In laravel i'm returning 401 :

```
  if (! $token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {  
            return response()->json(['status'=>true,'error_message' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not success block. A subscribe takes 3 arguments.

1.Next

2.Error

3.Complete

No matter what happens to your observable(success or error), if you write a complete method it always will be called. so in order to prevent this, put those 4 lines in Next method

```
this.authService.signin(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
    (result: any) => {
      this.responseHandler(result);
      this.authState.setAuthState(true);
      this.loginForm.reset()
      this.toastr.success('Success', 'Logged In Successfully');
      this.router.navigate(['user/dashboard']);
    },
    error => {
      this.errors = error.error;
      if(this.errors.error_message){
          this.toastr.error('', this.errors.error_message);
      }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer so should I write these lines where response handler method is called if on success? And then how will I show message in case of 401

Comment: I'm not sure what's your goal. I edited my answer and I think it will fix your error

Comment: Issue is i'm returning 401 from my controller incase if login credentials does not match i.e. unauthorised 401 is being returned then control in not going inside success block neither error block can you please let me know the solution to catch 401

Comment: i want to show message to user `invalid login` in case of 401

Comment: error block will catch any error including 401. probably this.errors.error_message does not exist. just make a simple console.log in first line error and check if it's called. if yes then check why did you write this line       

this.errors = error.error;

Comment: in my case there was http interceptor that was handling 401 error. Thanks